# Entity vs Schema in Normalizr

Tags: javascript, normalization

I'm learning how to use [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr). What's the difference between a schema and an entity?

Comment: Very broadly, a schema is a spec for a data structure, while an entity is a piece of data.

Comment: So like a class vs an instance?